# How to keep ajax data after submit on dropdown lists and display selected value?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have 2 dropdown lists, one is populated by ajax. I'd like to keep the data from the ajax dropdown list after submit and display the selected values but I don't know how
here's my code :

```
    <select name="centrale" class="custom-select" id="centrale">
        <option value="" >Centrales</option>
        <option value="all" <?php if(isset($centrale) && $centrale=='all') echo "selected='select'";?> >Toutes centrales</option>
        <option value="LECASUD" <?php if(isset($centrale) && $centrale=='LECASUD') echo "selected='select'";?> >LECASUD</option>
        <option value="SCACENTRE" <?php if(isset($centrale) && $centrale=='SCACENTRE') echo "selected='select'";?> >SCACENTRE</option>
</select>
    <select id="magasins" name="magasins" class="custom-select">
    </select>




    $('#centrale').on('change',function(){
    $('#magasins').html("<option value='allMag'>tout magasins</option>");
    var centrale =$(this).val();
    if (centrale){
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'ajaxMag.php',
            data:'centrale='+centrale,
            success:function(html){
            $('#magasins').append(html);
            }
        });
    }
    });
```

Comment: if you're submitting via a normal postback (i.e. not via AJAX), then what you get back afterwards is a whole new HTML document. Anything you did in the previous version is destroyed. So if you want to preserve something which was loaded via AJAX during that previous page's life, you have to post back that something along with your other data, then the server can use that information to re-create the same HTML content when it creates the new page to send back to the browser.

Comment: Hi @Valerie, value is inserting into DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
</head>

<body>
    <SELECT type = "text" id = "centrale">
        <option value="abc">ABC</option>
        <option value="cdf">CDF</option>
    </SELECT>

    <SELECT type = "text" id = "magasins" onchange ="save_magasins();">
        <option value="asd">asd</option>
        <option value="dfg">fdg</option>
    </SELECT>

    <input type = "button" id = "submit_btn">
</body>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#centrale').on('change',function(){
        //réinitialise la liste sinon les selections s'ajoutent
        $('#magasins').html("<option value='allMag'>tout magasins</option>");
        var centrale = $(this).val();

        if (centrale){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'ajaxMag.php',
                data:{centrale:centrale},
                success:function(html){
                    $('#magasins').append(html);
                }

            });
        }
    });
});

function save_magasins(){
    var magasins = document.getElementById('magasins').value;             
    window.localStorage.setItem("magasins", magasins);
    console.log(localStorage.getItem("magasins"));
}

console.log(localStorage.getItem("magasins"));

</script>
```

Try this. Now i'm trying to save your second drop down values based on an `onchange` trigger. If you want to save all the option from your second drop down then better save them first inside the success function itself and then populate. If you want to save only the selected option then this will work just fine.